# Why is this becoming an infinite loop?

Tags: java

All i need this method to do is take a string lets say `"aaxbb"` and it will return `true` because there is an 'aa' and a 'bb',

If the string given is `length = 0` or `length = 1` it should fail.

The issue i'm having is that which i do not know.. i know that in my terminal after hasAdjacentPair's first test case Pass's, i get a blinking curser meaning that somehwere in this method i'm not kicking out of one of my loops for it to continue to check the string for any more adjacent pairs

the first test case passes while its an empty string "" = because it returned false

the second test case passes while its "a" = because it returned false

We are also not allowed to use Arrays :(

```
public boolean hasAdjacentPair(String str)
    {
       boolean result = false;

       if (str.length() == 0)
       {
           result = false;
       }
       if (str.length() == 1)
       {
           result = false;
       }

       while (str.length() != 0)
       {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; ++i)
        {
            char adjChar = str.charAt(i);
            char nextAdjChar = str.charAt(i + 1);

            if (adjChar == nextAdjChar)
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }

       }
    return result;
    }
```

Changed my while loop `while (str.length() != 0)` to while `(str.length() != 0 && str.length() != 1)`  this enabled test 2 to work

EDIT 2 : After i completely took out the `while (str.length() != 0)` All 5 of my test cases pass :) so i guess it was just that?

Comment: You never change the str variable within your while loop, so its length never becomes zero, and so when will the loop ever stop?

Comment: `while (str.length() != 0)` how can the length of the `String` be anything other than what it is?

Comment: any expression you user for `while` has to be modified inside the loop so that the expression returns false under some cirumstances to avoid infinite loop. in your case, once it enters, the `str` variable is never changed. so it never exits

Comment: Thanks guys xD silly mistakes <3 appreciate it

Comment: This is the sort of bug you should be able to solve using your debugger.  I would run the code in the debugger, pause it and most likely it will be in your infinite loop.  Then you can step through the code to see why it is in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (str.length() != 0)
```

is always true and loop never end. Instead of if..if..while structure use either switch on length of string or if-else.

You could try something like this

```
if (str.length() == 0)
   {
       result = false;
   }
   else if (str.length() == 1)
   {
       result = false;
   }

   else
   {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; ++i)
    {
        char adjChar = str.charAt(i);
        char nextAdjChar = str.charAt(i + 1);

        if (adjChar == nextAdjChar)
        {
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

If you checking for atleast one pair make use of break statement as you already know that you got the result

Comment: what could i use as an alternative statement? or could i just take this out completely? @user3694267

Comment: @ErikVorcov it depends, when do you want the while loop to end?

Comment: appreciate it @user3694267

Answer (score 1):

try this  alternative:

```
boolean c = false;
//Your other code
while (str.length() != 0 && c == false)
       {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; ++i)
        {
            char adjChar = str.charAt(i);
            char nextAdjChar = str.charAt(i + 1);

            if (adjChar == nextAdjChar)
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        c = true;
        }
//Your other code
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you have a while loop checking for the `str` length?  The `str` is not modified in the loop.

What you most likely want is an if, else if, else structure.

You can most likely return true within the `adjChar == nextAdjChar` if statement and return false at the end of your function.